# Native Base Medium/Bold fonts show up the same as Regular font

Tags: react-native, fonts, native-base

I'm building a react native app, and I've linked my fonts to my projects. For iOS, i'm having trouble with the font variations. I am using the Roboto font family, and no matter what font weight variation I use, it shows up as "Roboto-Regular".

If I do:
fontFamily: 'Roboto-Medium' or
fontFamily: 'Roboto-Bold'

It displays the same as Roboto-Regular. I am not having this issue in Android. The fonts folder is added to the Bundle Resources, and to the info.plist.

Just to test things out further if i do:
fontFamily: 'Roboto-sMedium' it will show a warning message "Unrecognized fontFamily", and revert to a system default font.

There is no problem in xcode recognizing the font family, but I cannot get the Medium and Bold variations to show properly.

Any suggestions?

--edit--

I figured out this was an issue with the Native Base elements I am using, where the style attributes were not recognizing the font weight variations on any Native Base elements.

For example, the `<Text>` element from Native Base didn't recognize the font weight variation of `style={{fontFamily: 'Roboto-Medium'}}`

If I switched to the react native `<Text>` element it would work appropriately.

I realize that you need to customize the them in Native Base to use the font properties as noted here:
https://docs.nativebase.io/customizing-fonts

However, I did not expect that the font-family style attributes would not work.